# Parsing a JSON that has an array in one of the values in Snowflake

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a variant column in tableA which has JSON data. I am trying to parse the data and insert to another table. When I try to parse an array value, am not able to get the array brackets out.

**Table A:**
|response                                           |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|{"survey_Id": "100","values": {"survey_Date": "10/19/2021","survey_TEXT": "Speech Language Pathologist","survey_options_selected": ["EMAIL"],"Time": "4:00 PM"}}                                                    |
|{"survey_Id": "101","values": {"survey_Date": "10/20/2021","survey_TEXT": "Nurse","survey_options_selected": ["SMS","EMAIL","PHONE"],"Time": "5:00 PM"}}                                                    |

**Snowflake query:**

```
SELECT 
response:survey_id::varchar, 
response:values:survey_date::varchar, 
response:values:survey_options_selected::varchar, 
response:values:Time::varchar
from tableA
```

The column survey_options_selected is returning the value in an array format

```
["EMAIL]
["SMS","EMAIL","PHONE"]
```

instead of the below expected output.

**Expected output:**

| survey_Id | survey_Date | survey_options_selected | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10/19/2021 | EMAIL | 4:00 PM |
| 101 | 10/20/2021 | SMS, EMAIL, PHONE | 5:00 PM |

Could you please tell me what i can change to get the output in the desired format?

Comment: Use [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html)

Comment: Thank you :) It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html) with a separator as comma.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. It worked. Thank you